# Relaciones de modelos en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo tres modelos:

- producto
- pedido
- detallePedido

Si el detalle del pedido solo puede tener un pedido(o un pedido solo un detalle de pedido)
Si el detalle del pedido puede tener varios productos

¿Como serian las relaciones en estos modelos?
¿Como quedaria el parametro "on_delete" en ambos casos?

Dentro de "detallePedido" tengo los atributos de "producto" y "pedido"

```
class detallePedido(models.Model):
    pedido = models._ _ _ _ (Pedido, on_delete= _ _ _ _)

    producto = models._ _ _ _(Producto, on_delete= _ _ _ _)
```

Comment: Un detalle de pedido, puede tener una "orden" y viceversa, pero que exactamente es esa "orden"? es un pedido?

Comment: cambie , la explicacion, me habia equivocado

Answer (score 2):

*Si el detalle del pedido puede tener varios productos*

Me parece que existe un problema de lógica si lo quieres hacer de esa manera, es que lo que estás diciendo es que quieres una relación Many-to-One (Varios a uno) entre DetallePedido y Producto, y para hacer eso en Django tendrías que declarar un campo de detallePedido en el modelo de Producto, y creo que eso no es lo que buscas, por lo general se entiende que un Pedido se hace por varios Productos, y la tabla/modelo DetallePedido vendría a romper esa relación donde por cada Detalle se corresponde un Producto.
Creo que lo mas recomendable, aunque desconozco la naturaleza entera de tu sistema, es que tengas el siguiente esquema:

- Pedido pudiendo tener varios DetallePedido
- DetallePedido pudiendo tener un Producto
- Producto pudiendo tener varios DetallePedido

Esto se consigue con el código que verás más abajo usando ForeignKeys para pedido y producto en tu modelo de Detalle.

Con respecto a que asignar en los on_delete dependería mucho de como quieres que se comporte el sistema pero puedes guiarte un poco por la lógica; al borrarse un Pedido quizas también quieres que se borren sus DetallePedidos correspondientes con él, ya que no tiene mucho sentido unos Detalles sin un registro del Pedido, entonces pondríamos CASCADE, pero si se borra un Producto quizas no convenga eliminar los DetallePedido para que tu sistema mantenga un registro de los Pedidos hechos, entonces pondríamos SET_NULL para que nada mas deje NULL el campo de la relación en la base de datos

```
class detallePedido(models.Model):
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Espero se haya entendido y sea de utilidad para tu caso. Responderé cualquier duda.

Comment: El detalle de pedido contiene todos los productos que el usuario haya comprado